# How to create a batch script which takes list of files as argument and passes to an exe

Tags: batch-file, directory, filepath

I am trying to create a batch file which runs an exe with arguments.
The exe needs an input file as argument.

Instead of specifying file name as argument, I would like to consider all files residing in that folder as input to exe.

Below is the syntax I have used in the batch script and executed it. Upon running below code batch script stopping suddenly.

However, when I specify the file name and run from command prompt the execution is successful.

Example:

```
Example.exe -i c:\Test\*.wav -o c:\result
```

I have looked at few of the examples in Google and found that I can use `*.fileextension` to refer that particular files in the folder.

I am thinking if there is a better approach to achieve this.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  Show us the script, tell us how you launched it.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you will run the same command and switch for multiple `wav` files.

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.wav) do (
     example.exe -i %%i -o c:\result
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Second procedure gave me the result i was looking.